# How to programmatically change php.ini values via shell scripts?

Tags: bash, rhel5

Basically, I'm trying to setup a shell script that lets me autoconfigure some parameters on my new servers

In particular, I'd like to set, in php.ini

error_log= /var/log/php_errors.log
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED

In my bash script I have this:

```
ERROR_REPORTING="error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED"
ERROR_LOG="/var/log/php_errors.log"

#CREATE LOG FILE 
sed -i 's/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = '${ERROR_REPORTING}'/' /etc/php.ini
touch $ERROR_LOG
chown apache:apache $ERROR_LOG
#The ; in the next line is because the line is commented by default on RHEL5
sed -i 's/;error_log = .*/error_log = '${ERROR_LOG}'/' /etc/php.ini
```

However, this does not appear to work and the error is not obvious to me..could anybody please correct my error?

Comment: It would help if you were specific regarding how it does not appear to work and also posted the error message.

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the outermost single quotes to double quotes and remove the single quotes around the variable names.

```
ERROR_REPORTING="E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED"
ERROR_LOG="/var/log/php_errors.log"

#CREATE LOG FILE 
sed -i "s/error_reporting = .*/error_reporting = ${ERROR_REPORTING}/" /etc/php.ini
touch $ERROR_LOG
chown apache:apache $ERROR_LOG
#The ; in the next line is because the line is commented by default on RHEL5
sed -i "s/;error_log = .*/error_log = ${ERROR_LOG}/" /etc/php.ini
```

Note that I also changed the first variable and the related `sed` command so it parallels the other set.

I'm assuming the error message you were getting was "unterminated `s' command".

Answer (score 0):

`sed -i` requires an argument that is used as the suffix for the backup file it creates.

Example: `sed -i .bak 's/old/new/' testfile` will create a backup `testfile.bak` before editing the original in place. Your command is taking the command string as the backup suffix (and, naturally, failing).

I'd also use double quotes on the command string. It'll save you having to mess around with extra single quoutes around the variable expansion.

Comment: That's true on OS X. GNU `sed` (which is what the OP is using in RHEL) does not require a suffix (it will accept an optional one).

Comment: Oh dear. I've spent the last 8-10 years thinking sed required that suffix :D.